# error when retrieve values from google script spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have this script in google script spreadsheet:

```js
function doGet() {
  var response = [];
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var thisSheet = ss.getSheetByName('product');
  var lastRow = thisSheet.getLastRow();
  
  var allValues = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues();
  
  var objectResponse = {};
  
  for(var i = 2; i < lastRow ; ++i){
    
    objectResponse.title = allValues[i][1];
    objectResponse.url = allValues[i][8];
    
    response.push(objectResponse);
  };
   
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(response)).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}
```

I make this loop to create an `array` of objects like this

```js
[
   { title: 'first_title_on2column'  , URL: 'first_url_on9column'},
   { title: 'second_title_on2column'  , URL: 'second_url_on9column'},
   ...
   //until ends <lastRow>
]
```

but the results is the same on each object. Same 'title' and 'URL'.

### How to retrieve each 'title' and 'URL' values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code does not add new object elements to the response array, but only new references to the same object - so all your values are the same

```
  var objectResponse = {};
  
  for(var i = 2; i < lastRow ; ++i){
    
    objectResponse.title = allValues[i][1];
    objectResponse.url = allValues[i][8];
    
    response.push(objectResponse);
  };
```

try replacing your code block with a new one and see what happens

```
  for(var i = 2; i < lastRow ; ++i){
    response.push({title: allValues[i][1], url:allValues[i][8]});
  };
```

or even like this

```
allValues.forEach(dataRow => response.push({title: dataRow[1], dataRow[8]}))
```